# Automatic rebuilding dependencies (makefiles)

Tags: c, makefile, build, dependencies

I have a huge project which is compiled with GCC.
I know that usually preforming build should rebuilds all **not** up-to-date dependencies but some of the **.h** files that we change does not cause rebuilding of the files which uses them. There is a hierarchy of make files, the main make file include the needed make file according to the need.
is there a way to insure rebuilding of the files which "#include" recently modified .h files?

Comment: Declare in the makefile on which files each target depends. Some tools can create such a dependency list automatically.

Comment: In a makefile there are rules which files should be checked to decide on rebuild. Usually this includes only the source files. Just add your .H files to the ruleset.

Comment: [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)

Comment: @Devolus Since it's a big projects with several makefiles and a lot of .h files it's not reasonable to add all of them, I'm trying to understand the reason of which some of them doesn't force rebuilding the objects corresponding to them. 
if I change the c files it will always detect the change and force rebuild.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie which tools? it would help a lot

Comment: tools? You already have it: gcc. See option `-M` which will create a dependency file that you basically just need to include into your main Makefile. Only a few lines to add if your Makefile is structured properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your header-files are correctly listed in the prerequisites. For large projects, it's not feasible to do this by hand, but the combination of `gcc` (or `clang`) and GNU Make gives you a powerful way to automate it.

Assuming you have some pretty standard Makefile using pattern rules:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
OBJS := main.o module.o

all: program

program: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

Then you can use the automatic remaking of Makefiles capability of GNU Make to include files adding additional prerequisites that are generated by `gcc`:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
OBJS := main.o module.o

all: program

program: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o$@ $^

# rule to create "dependency files", make the dependency file itself
# depend on the same prerequisites
%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -MM -MT"$@ $(@:.d=.o)" -MF$@ $(CFLAGS) $<

# include dependency files except for targets not building anything
ifneq ($(filter-out clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
endif

# add Makefiles themselves to prerequisites here (with a changed Makefile,
# the only safe thing is to rebuild all):
%.o: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o$@ $<

# remove dependency files on clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.d

.PHONY: all clean
```

This is just an example, there are a lot of possibilities how you could use these features.

Comment: the main question is, do i have to specify all of the .h files independently or prerequisite the source (c) files should be enough?

Comment: Make will not parse your C files.  All the .h files must be specified as dependencies separately.  Felix is showing you how to have the compiler do this for you automatically rather than having to do it by hand.  You might also read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ for a different (better, IMO) way to do it than the above.

Comment: @Itay Either you didn't understand my answer and MadScientists comment -- or I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have a mechanism to create a .d (dependency file) which includes (the path and name) the .h files that are in the issue, and in the makefile output in debug it looks like it check the .d file for dependencies, still the changes are not forcing rebuild.

in the debug mode:
"Trying implicit prerequisite 'ObjNAME/.d/handlers.d'.
       Found an implicit rule for 'ObjNAME/handlers.o'."

in the .d file:
"../../Device/handlers.h \"

thanks